# Gradle Slf4j/Log4j logging in tests

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, slf4j

I'm using Gradle to run tests in my project. A third party library is printing a warning + stacktrace via Slf4J to the console. This is causing alot of noise in the test output so I would like to suppress it. I have configured Slf4j & Log4J as dependencies on my project and placed log4j.xml with root level error in src/test/resources. The warning is still being printed so it appears Gradle is not picking up my logging configuration.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: What you're doing is correct. Maybe the library is using something other than SLF4J. I'm assuming you are seeing this behavior when building with Gradle directly, not through an IDE.

Comment: Hmm, I've checked the source of the third party lib and it is using slf4j for sure. Correct, seeing this when running from withing Gradle, not through IDE.